# Why cannot disable PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES?

Tags: pdo

I am using PHP 5.2.9 and Apache 2.2.11 and mysql 5.1.32

Why I cannot disable PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES ?

Below is the code :

```
<?php
try{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$DB_SERVER;dbname=$DB_NAME",$DB_USER,$DB_PASS, array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false)); 
}

catch(PDOException $pe){
    die('Connection error : ' .$pe->getMessage());
}

$st = $conn->prepare('abc');
echo "emulate : " . $st->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES);
?>
```

output is "emulate : 1". I also tried the code :

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);
```

but the output is still the same value "1". The output should be 0 if the value is false right? But why the output is 1? How to disable ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES?

Answer (score 3):

your code works for me on PHP 5.3.6 and mysqld 5.1.58 (it returns false and really uses prepares), try to upgrade PHP to >= 5.3 to see if it is version issue (if so then update is probably your only solution).

Despite that even if you manage to set this flag it doesn't really mean that PDO will use prepared statement, if you want to check if PDO really uses prepares (and you can use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) ) you could write simple script which does prepared query:

```
<?php
    $pdo = new PDO(..., array(ATTR::PDO_EMULATE_PREPARES => false));
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT :param');
    $stmt->bindValue(':param', 5);
    $stmt->execute();
```

sniff the transmission until you find you query "SELECT :param" - if :param was replaced with question mark, then PDO uses prepares. If it was replaced by '5' then PDO emulates prepares.

Comment: if it was replaced by '5' then it mean the statement is not using bound parameter. Bound parameter is used for preventing SQL injection, but now emulate prepares doesn't use bound parameter, so it can't prevent SQL injection right? So I have to set emulate prepares => false then only it can prevent SQL injection right?

Comment: it protects you from SQL Injection as long as it escapes parameters correctly - and it does.

Comment: I tested on my online web hosting which is running php version 5.2.14 is able to disable emulate prepare. So it is not php version issue. I guess WAMP Server offline localhost can't disable emulate?

Comment: so maybe its windows problem - I have tested on linux, your hosting is probably linux as well. But is it really a problem for you that prepares are emulated? From application point of view it makes no difference at all.

Comment: Yes, my hosting is Linux. I just worry it can't prevent SQL injection fully if I don't disable emulate prepare. You said if param is "5" instead of "?", then it is emulate prepare. I assume param "5" didn't escape parameters correctly.